# Get Email of a current logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins, syntax

I am trying to modify a WordPress plugin (CF7), and I am stuck in the middle of the way.

Site is a bit specific, that is the reason, I need this functionality.

In the contact form I get a receiver address from a custom field, saved in a post.

The code is like that:

```
.
.
elseif ( '_post_email' == $name )
$output = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'email', true);  
.
.
```

_post_email is then used as some kind of a shortcode on a contact form (cf7_special_mail_tag).

What I want now, is to get the same way the e-mail of the registered user, who is in fact sending the form. I want this because the user who receive mail can be able to reply.

I tried this, but unfortunately its not working

```
elseif ( '_post_email_sender' == $name )
$output = wp_get_current_user( 'user_email' );
```

Comment: have you tried using the 

`$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` then getting the email with `$current_user->user_email` It looks like that is what you are trying, is it?

Comment: Are you doing other modifications to the plugin or is this the only one?

Comment: Some other but should not interfere with that change.